# How to read metadata of one EC2 instance in another EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In a multinode scenario, where there is one master EC2 instances and multiple EC2 worker instances, is there a way to read the metadata of worker instances by the master instance?. What is the best way to do it?. Can it be done just with Python script?.

Mainly interested in getting the interruption-notice of spot instances.

Comment: I think you can manage everything AWS programmatically, though I might be wrong. I think [the `describe-instances` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) works for this particular problem, though I don't use AWS to test it out. You can probably parse the output in Python. There may be a premade Python library to do it, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about reading metadata of an instance from other instance using `https://169.254.169.254` then the simple answer is No. You cannot do that.

However, everything that is exposed in the meta-data can be accessed using `AWS SDK`.

`interruption-notice` for the Spot Instance is published as Cloudwatch event or you can query `describe-spot-instance-requests` and filter with the `instance id`. ( I have not done it but it looks like it is possible to do so). You will get the `Status` in the output.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-spot-instance-requests.html

Comment: *Everything*?  Including [interruption-notice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html)?

Comment: Not the interruption-notice. It is not technically the instance metadata. However, It is published as Cloudwatch event though.

Comment: It is, indeed.  You might add that to the answer, since that seems like the right solution, here.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : spot instance state can be read using `describe-spot-instance-requests` API call.

Comment: I am looking for "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/termination-time ", but want this to be sent to another instance (master).
describe-spot-instances does not seem to expose this.
If the worker instance reads it's "termination-time" metadata, is there a way for it to send it to the master instance?

Comment: @user1650281: There is nothing out-of-the-box to do what you are describing. You can write a custom solution to do that.